# How can I use postfix to filter out invalid emails before they go to smtp relay

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta

I am trying to use postfix and/or maildev or some other tool to filter out emails with bad addresses before they go to my external smtp server.

I have automated tests that were built to be sent to a spam catchall site mailforspam.com.  The code has been written but I don't see a need to send all this mail to an external site.  In addition, I have users who are sending traffic to other non-existing accounts or domains.  I set up maildev on a server and configured my server to send all its mail to maildev.  However, every time a user uses a bogus email such as abc@xyz.com, maildev crashes because it waits on a response that never comes or it fails to look up a host.  I can use maildev to sinkhole all the traffic (ie not relay) but then legitimate traffic gets blocked as well.  I am trying to use postfix transport maps to filter mail destined for certain domains or users so they don't leave the network via smtp.

I have maildev running on 10.231.20.201 using port 1025.

I set up post fix on port 25 of the same machine (10.231.20.201).  I added a transport map in /etc/postfix/transport

and it has the following entries:

```
* relay:10.231.20.201:1025
```

If I just have the one entry above, all mail gets sinkholed correctly but no mail goes out.

If I change it to:

```
mailforspam.com 10.231.20.201:1025
* relay:smtp.mydomain.com
```

It doesn't route to the mailserver the mailforspam.com traffic and instead routes everything to the outside world.  With the volume of automated tests that are running, the bad emails clog up the smtp servers -- not too mention sending out spam.

If I set the postfix transport map to:

```
mailforspam.com 10.231.20.201:1025
* relay:smtp.mydomain.com
```

And I send a simple message using swaks like:

```
echo "test message" | swaks --to josephspam@mailforspam.com --from "jishak@mydomain.coom" -s 10.231.20.201 -p 25
```

Then when I send a test mail to that domain, I see the following in /var/log/maillog:

```
May 20 20:49:49 maildev postfix/error[12649]: 109C819C5A13: to=<josephspam@mailforspam.com>, relay=none, delay=6111, delays=6111/0.03/0/0.02, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
```

I am trying to figure out the proper way to relay email heading to a domain outside my control to a spamtrap such as maildev.

I also need to still let legitimate email go on to the proper smtp relay.

Has anyone done this before?  Any ideas?

The main problems I see are that 
1.  I can't properly figure out how to route emails to the spamtrap
2.  Some rules are in the transport map but I can't get them to work with the maildev server running on 1025 of the same box as it seems the rules only work on port 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

I set the /etc/postfix/transport file to explicitly blacklist certain domains that my developers are known to abuse such as values that are hardcoded in configuration files, values from previous companies that owned my current company but are not easy to change, etc.

I explicitly whitelist traffic that people have requested and aren't being abused such as:

```
aol.com smtp:[external_mail_server_ip]:25
gmail.com smtp:[external_mail_server_ip]:25
icloud.com smtp:[external_mail_server_ip]:25
mycompany.com smtp:[external_mail_server_ip]:25
```

I opted to block all traffic and only whitelist specific sites and email addresses that are not being abused.

```
* relay:[maildev_mail_server_ip]:1025
```

Also, at some point mailforspam.com probably got tired of the traffic coming from our domain which was legitimate but more than they could handle so the just dropped all the packets.  I ended up blacklisting that domain to the maildev server and asked the developers to just check the mail in maildev using maildev's api.